# JSON Post Request Design Pattern not quite SOLID

Tags: java, json, design-patterns

I designed an abstract class that defines a GetJsonRequset and a POstJsonRequest.

My abstract class is defined along with the method signature as follows:

```
public abstract class RequestBuilder
  {
    protected object GetJsonRequest(string connectionUriString, string queryString, Func<string,object> parseDelegate )

    protected object PostJsonRequest(string connectionUriString, string queryString, string inputBody, Func<string,object> parseDelegate )


....

}
```

Now all child classes pass in a delegate as follows.

```
public class ProjectListBuilder : RequestBuilder
  {
     public ProjectContext Build()
        {
          this.AddRequestHeader("TokenKey", this.authenticationModel.TokenKey);
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.page))
          {
            this.AddRequestHeader("Page", this.page);
          }      
          string connectionstring = String.Concat(this.authenticationModel.ServiceBaseUrl, projectURI);
          List<ProjectModel> projectModels = (List<ProjectModel>)GetJsonRequest(connectionstring, string.Empty, Parse);
          return new ProjectContext(this.authenticationModel, this.page, projectModels);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// delegate used to parse resonse from server. Converts Json from server to strongly type object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<ProjectModel> Parse(string json)
        {
          DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectModel>));
          using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
          {
            return (List<ProjectModel>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
          }      
        }
}
```

This works and is fine for a first pass, but it has a weird smell to it. How can i re-factor this to meet a more SOLID design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `ProjectListBuilder` actually responsible for *building the request*? Or does it also parse the response by the means of the delegate (SRP)? You might want to make that delegate injectable.

The `Build` method name is uclear to me. Seems like it also issues the request, but if this is the case, then the name is misleading.

What does `GetJsonRequest` and `PostJsonRequest` return? I would expect an request object which can be send to server, but I don't know, since the return type is `object`. Also `object` is a nasty thing as it does boxing and unboxing which takes CPU time. Use interfaces (Interface segragation principle) e.g.:

```
interface Request
{
    public Response send();
}
```

Or better yet: use generics:

```
interface Request<TResponse>
{
    public TResponse send();
}
```

You could also inject the delegate here:

```
interface Request<TResponse>
{
    public TResponse send(Func<string, TResponse> responseParser);
}
```

I would also separete the specific builders and make use of nested classes:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest<TResponse> : Request<TResponse>
{
    // ...
}

public class GetJsonRequest<TResponse> : BaseRequest<TResponse>
{
    public class Builder
    {
        // ...
        public GetJsonRequest<TResponse> Build()
        {
            // ...
            return new GetJsonRequest<TResponse>(uri, page);
        }
    }

    // ...

    public TResponse send(Func<string, TResponse> responseParser)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So I could use it like this:

```
var builder = new GetJsonRequest<Project>.Builder();
builder.setPage(page);
builder.setUri(uri);
GetJsonRequest<Project> request = builder.Build();
Project myProject = request.send(json => ParseProjectJson(json))
```

Nice and clean.

Comment: My ProjectListBuilder was responsible for making the request and parsing the response and return a ProjectContext object that had access to the Model. Other objects use the context object to query the strongly typed Json response model. As I write this I see that my builder is perhaps responsible for too much.